# playbook error while import certicate to java keystore thorugh ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible  please help me with this

ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/test1.yml': line 4, column 26, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
      - name: Import SSL certificate from google.com to a keystore, create it if it doesn't exist
            java_cert:
                     ^ here
```

**yml file-**

tasks:
`          - name: Import SSL certificate from google.com to a keystore, create it if it doesn't 
                java_cert:
                        cert_url: google.com
                        keystore_path: /tmp/cacerts
                        keystore_pass: changeit
                        keystore_create: yes
                        state: present

Comment: Whitespace is important. `java_cert` should be indented to the same level as `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
- name: Import SSL certificate from google.com to a keystore, ..
  java_cert:
```

The j of `java_cert` must be under the n of `name`

P.S. indent your code also here in stackoverflow